# How do I skin my Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, skinning

I want to change the look and feel of my application to be similar to [Office 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2007).

Are there any ready-made, easy, simple, solutions available?

Comment: Do you want a ribbon? Are you prepared to pay money for a solution?

Comment: There is significant difference between "skinning" and "changing the look and feel" of your application - the skinning assumes that you want to have multiple looks and be able to switch between them, while "changing the look and feel" refers to just changing your GUI appearance - so which one is it?

Comment: Just changing GUI appreance, no switching between themes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Free [Krypton toolkit](https://www.componentsource.com/product/krypton-toolkit)

> The toolkit comes with themes that
>   match Office 2007, Office 2010 and
>   many others.

**Disclaimer: This has now been discontinued by the publisher. Use at your own risk.**

Comment: My company has been using Krytpon for 4 years.  Its very stable. I think I've had maybe 4 bugs in 4 yeas? Its appearance is becoming dated, but it is still a huge improvement over standard WinForms.

Comment: This is now discontinued by the publisher

Comment: The author has placed the full source code as open source on GitHub! https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton. It is also available as a Nuget package. Just search for Krypton. Hint: If you grab one of the extended toolkit suites, there are dozens of new themes to choose from.

Answer (score 8):

We used [Infragistics Net Advantage](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms.aspx) for theme and skinning.. They do support Office 2007 styles.

Comment: not Infrastructure, Infragistics

Comment: @Milan, Denis sorry, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

For a great .NET component suite, use [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/), pricey but great