# C# app look and feel (theme)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, look-and-feel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I skin my Winform application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329632/how-do-i-skin-my-winform-application)

I know this is maybe an already debated subject, but I can't managed to find a simple answer to walk me through the rest of the process neither here nor by googling.

Basically what I need to do, is to change the whole theme of an application I've developed in C# WinForms. Just like applying a new look-and-feel in Java, without having to style each element individually everytime.

More than that, I would like to use a style like the VS2010's default (with the same colours). Do you think there is a library that I can download and apply?

Another approach I thought of, is to somehow extend the Forms, and overwrite the colours myself for each element, then use it in all my windows.

I repeat, the goal is mainly to change the colours, as by enabling visual styles, the shapes and layout are ok.

Thank you!

====================================================================

LE:
Ok, so I've crawled the net, and seems there's no quick way to do this. Now, I decided to recolor all the default winforms' controls. Does anyone know how to access them? (eg. for a textbox I will have tb.BackgroundColor) ...but I need for every single element in the GUI (like background of selected items etc). Thank you!

Comment: Just do a search on `winforms skinning` here at SO and you'll get a lot of answers. If they are not good enough for you: describe why.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your feedback. I've searched the site before, but couldn't find a concrete answer if I can do this by myself, or with the help of a free framework. I thought of buying a DevExpress license, but is way too expensive for me (~900$). And it does not worth it just for a change of colours.

So, how could I do this by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the BackColor property of your Controls?

e.g.

```
BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 100);
panel1.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;
```

You can also create a panel type to use across your application. Something like:

```
class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
MyPanel panel2 = new MyPanel();
Controls.Add(panel2);
```

Comment: There are a lot of elements to be colored this way, it's not just some buttons and panels' backgrounds. But thanks for your contribution.