# Beautifying a Windows Form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I will be creating a small database-driven [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application for my C# project. I wanted to beautify it like we do on web sites using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). Are there any resources or sites which can help me in beautifying my application?

Comment: Telerik have a tool to do this you can get a free trial.  Check out their demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/formdecorator/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Also, checkout the free trial with devexpress: http://www.devexpress.com/products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/

Comment: http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3 has a free version and is quite nice (referenced in my answer via the first link).

Comment: Personal experience from maintaining a skinned 7-year-old WinForms application: don't. These things are very difficult to use, have a tendency to break with new OS releases and themes, support localization and automation poorly, get end-of-lifed long before your app does and, after a few years, look dated and gimmicky not "beautiful". Use the standard built-in controls or, if those do not provide the features you need, use WPF.

Answer (score 8):

You could try a library I built some time ago.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33716/Fancy-Windows-Forms

Comment: Beautiful work. what a talent!

Comment: Hello... I installed it for a new Winforms project, usingVisual Studio 2019, but when I try to enter design mode of the form, an error is shown. Application is run with the fancy look though. Maybe there is an incompatibility issue with VS2019? This is the actual designer error: `The designer for this file cannot be displayed because none of the classes it contains can be designed`

Answer (score 7):

"Beautify" and "Windows Forms" are not often used in the same sentence.  WPF allows for significantly better design opportunities.

Some frameworks allow you to skin a WinForms application, which allows you to drive look through configuration rather than code.

[How do I skin my Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329632/how-do-i-skin-my-winform-application)

There's also a CodeProject project that provides a skinner, though I have not used it personally

http://catalog.codeproject.com/Articles/415102/WinForms-Form-Skin

When I used to write small WinForms utilities without access to a framework, I would subclass each major control, and apply a style in that subclass.  One change to the subclass affects the entire app.

Comment: From the answers one thing I can notice, all solutions are paid ones, I wanted something like CSS. Looks like I have to use the boring controls only :P

Comment: The free version of Krypton Tools will get you quite far.  WinForms follows a different design paradigm than CSS.  If you don't embrace the WinForms design philosophy, you will feel like you're swimming upstream too often.

Answer (score 3):

CSS-like styling is difficult in Windows Forms, because the framework wasn't really built with it in mind.  If styling is important to you, then you will probably have a much easier time of it using WPF instead.

I know of one third-party library designed to help with skinning WinForms applications, [DevExpress WinForms Skins](http://www.devexpress.com/products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/).  I don't have real experience with with it, though, so I can't make any comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you google ".NET custom theme" then you can get many free styles to use in your projects.

Here is a list made by some user over at hackforums of his styles and custom controls, which I think help make your form 'Custom' and 'Nice': http://pastebin.com/1nvZ08kx

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CSS to style a WinForms application, but I don't think that's what you mean anyway.

As far as "beautifying" your application, there are a number of 3rd-party tools available. The most popular ones are (in no particular order):

- Telerik
- DevExpress
- Infragistics
- ComponentOne
- Many, many others

People tend to get religious about their 3rd-party design tooling, and a lot of ink has been spilled on SO going over the benefits of each 3rd-party design tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in third-party tools for designing Windows Forms applications you could also take a look at the Infragistic's one - AppStylist for Windows Forms controls. There is [a short video for the runtime version of this tool](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/appstylist/videos/appstylistruntime-getting-started).

Another useful page for getting started is *[Application Styling Framework](http://www.infragistics.com/help/topic/8CBDEFA7-3CFC-4EF1-8656-E7F646085126)*.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the WebBrowser control to create an interface before. With it you can use HTML and CSS to create a pretty nice looking "form". It requires a bit more coding, but it works. A user needs IE installed to use the control though. There is a VB.Net example here:
[Using VB .Net WebBrowser Control To Build WinForm User Interface](http://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/using-vb-net-webbrowser-control-to-build-winform-user-interface/)

In any case, it's another option.